# Peterson lock/unlock java implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, concurrency

I'm trying to implement the algorithm in the [title](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm), but at the moment is not working correctly:

```
package me.fponzi.mutex;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class PetersonLockUnlock implements MutexInterface {
    private AtomicInteger[] FLAG;
    private AtomicInteger[] LAST;
    private int N;

    /**
     * PetersonLockUnlock
     *
     * @param N number of processes.
     */
    public PetersonLockUnlock(int N) {
        this.N = N;

        this.FLAG = new AtomicInteger[N];
        this.LAST = new AtomicInteger[N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            this.FLAG[i] = new AtomicInteger(0);
            this.LAST[i] = new AtomicInteger(-1);
        }


    }

    public void lock(int i) {

        for (int l = 1; l < this.N-1; l++) {

            this.FLAG[i].set(l);
            this.LAST[l].set(i);
            boolean other_flags = true;
            while (other_flags && this.LAST[l].get() == i) {

                for (int k = 0; k < this.N; k++) {
                    if (k == i) continue;
                    other_flags = other_flags && this.FLAG[k].get() >= l;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void unlock(int i) {
        this.FLAG[i].set(0);
    }
}
```

This is the main class:

```
import me.fponzi.mutex.MutexInterface;
import me.fponzi.mutex.PetersonLockUnlock;

public class Main {
    static int test_value = 0;

    public static class PrintThread implements Runnable{
        private MutexInterface mutex;

        PrintThread(MutexInterface m)
        {
            this.mutex = m;
        }
        @Override
        public void run()  {
            String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            int threadId = Integer.parseInt(threadName);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                mutex.lock(threadId);
                test_value +=1;
                mutex.unlock(threadId);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final int NTHREADS = 100;

        PetersonLockUnlock p = new PetersonLockUnlock(NTHREADS);

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[NTHREADS];
        while (true) {
            test_value = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++) {
                threads[i] = new Thread(new PrintThread(p), "" + i);
            }

            for (Thread t : threads) {
                t.start();
            }
            for (Thread t : threads) {
                t.join();
            }
            System.out.println("Result:" + test_value);
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm creating 100 threads, and all of them increase the `test` variable 5 times. So the expected value should be 500. This is the ouptut:

```
Result:499
Result:500
Result:500
Result:500
Result:498
Result:499
Result:500
Result:499
Result:499
Result:500
Result:500
Result:500
Result:498
Result:500
Result:499
Result:500
Result:500
Result:499
Result:500
Result:500
Result:500
Result:500
Result:500
Result:500
Result:500
Result:500
Result:500
```

It looks like that sometimes there are two threads that are inside their critical section. 
I've also tried to used AtomicIntegerArray instead:

```
public class PetersonLockUnlock implements MutexInterface {
    private AtomicIntegerArray FLAG;
    private AtomicIntegerArray LAST;
    private int N;

    /**
     * PetersonLockUnlock
     *
     * @param N number of processes.
     */
    public PetersonLockUnlock(int N) {
        this.N = N;

        this.FLAG = new AtomicIntegerArray(N);
        this.LAST = new AtomicIntegerArray(N);

        for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) {
            this.FLAG.set(i, 0);
            this.LAST.set(i, 0);
        }


    }

    public void lock(int i) {

        for (int l = 1; l < this.N; l++) {

            this.FLAG.set(i, l);
            this.LAST.set(l, i);
            boolean other_flags = true;
            while (other_flags && this.LAST.get(l) == i) {

                for (int k = 0; k < this.N; k++) {
                    if (k == i) continue;
                    other_flags = other_flags && this.FLAG.get(k) >= l;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void unlock(int i) {
        this.FLAG.set(i,0);
    }
}
```

But still have the same problem. I've also tried to use `volatile` for the various members, but still dosen't work.

Comment: You are using AtomicInteger variables in lock method but it is not enough to make lock method thread-safe. You should do there some more sophisticated form of synchronization (I am not sure what exactly however).

Comment: Hello and thanks for the comment! Can you please elaborate more? I'm trying to implement the peterson algorithm for lock/unlock so the fact that the method is not thread safe should not be worried I think. Isn't it?

Comment: Shouldn't the loop be `int l = 0; l < N-1`?  FYI, you don't need to explicitly set the arrays to 0 in the second version.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for pointing that out. The second iteration was the results of other trials, in first code I still had -1. Even with it in the second version, it works in the same way. Also thanks for the initialization tip :)

Comment: But they're both starting at 1.

Comment: Uh, sorry, I thought you were talking about the N-1. No, it should be fine with l = 1. A thread in level 0 means that is not interested in acquiring the lock.

Comment: * In the unlock I use 0 to state that the thread is not interested in acquiring the lock. The algorithm described on wikipedia sets the flag to -1 in the unlock, while I set it to 0 so I think should be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid that the problem is that you haven't implemented Peterson's algorithm correctly.

Specifically, the outer loop in your `lock` method needs to start at zero, not at 1. And since zero is a valid value for thread number, you can't use it as "default" or "not in use value" for the levels array (I've renamed the FLAG and LAST arrays to the terms used in Wikipedia's description of [Peterson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm)). Instead, I changed the code to use -1 for that purpose.

Most importantly though, your implementation of this part of Peterson's algorithm

```
while last_to_enter[ℓ] = i and there exists k ≠ i, such that level[k] ≥ ℓ
    wait
```

is incorrect. Your function doesn't test for existence with `other_flags = other_flags && this.FLAG.get(k) >= l;`, since if there is one element in the array for which k >= l is not true, you set your other_flags to false. But the logic should be the other way around.

I've refactored that part into a separate method and fixed it there.

With those changes, it works. The memory barrier is implied as `AtomicInteger` uses a volatile variable, and a lock always read from the the AtomicInteger that was modified by the previous `unlock`, so it creates it happens-before relationship in the terminology of the Java Memory Model.

```
public class PetersonLockUnlock implements MutexInterface {
    private AtomicInteger[] levels;
    private AtomicInteger[] lastToEnter;
    private int n;

    public PetersonLockUnlock(int n) {
        this.n = n;

        this.levels = new AtomicInteger[n];
        this.lastToEnter = new AtomicInteger[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            this.levels[i] = new AtomicInteger(-1);
            this.lastToEnter[i] = new AtomicInteger(-1);
        }
    }

    public void lock(int i) {
        for (int l = 0; l < this.n - 1; l++) {
            this.levels[i].set(l);
            this.lastToEnter[l].set(i);
            while (this.lastToEnter[l].get() == i && existsLevelGteL(l, i)) {
                // busy-wait
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean existsLevelGteL(int l, int i) {
        for (int k = 0; k < this.n; k++) {
            if (k != i && this.levels[k].get() >= l) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void unlock(int i) {
        this.levels[i].set(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've not used the pseudocode in wikipedia but from a book, but I guess I should used that instead. I was looking for a problem like that because without the lock the code was still outputing similar numbers :) Thanks a lot again for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

I did some adjustments. Worked every time. Seems you have a problem with index 0.

```
public PetersonLockUnlock(int N) {
    this.N = N;

    this.FLAG = new AtomicInteger[N];
    this.LAST = new AtomicInteger[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        this.FLAG[i] = new AtomicInteger(-1);
        this.LAST[i] = new AtomicInteger(-1);
    }


}

public void lock(int i) {

    for (int l = 0; l < this.N-1; l++) {
        this.FLAG[i].set(l);
        this.LAST[l].set(i);
        boolean other_flags = true;
        while (other_flags && this.LAST[l].get() == i) {
            other_flags = false;
            for (int k = 0; k < this.N; k++) {
                if (k == i) continue;
                if (this.FLAG[k].get() >= l) {
                    other_flags = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public void unlock(int i) {
    this.FLAG[i].set(-1);
}
```